# "To continue using iCloud, confirm your new Mac password" keeps crashing

Tags: icloud, password, system-settings

I recently changed my Mac password, and a System Preferences notification comes up, asking me to "confirm Mac password to continue using iCloud":

[image]

However, when I click `Continue`, all that happens is a dropdown appears asking me to continue, then when I continue, nothing happens. I have no idea why this is happening, does anyone have any feedback?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try signing out of iCloud and then signing back in again.